# What argument(s) to translate pypy3 am I missing?

Tags: python, pypy

Trying to translate pypy3 on Ubuntu 14.04. I've followed the instructions here: http://pypy.readthedocs.org/en/latest/getting-started-python.html#installation, but I am getting an error.

```
pypy ../../rpython/bin/rpython -O2 --sandbox targetpypystandalone.py gives me

File "../../rpython/bin/rpython", line 17
print __doc__
     ^
SyntaxError: invalid syntax
```

Looking at the file rpython/bin/rpython I see an if statement that I seem to be hitting

```
if len(sys.argv) == 1:
    print __doc__
    sys.exit(1)
```

What arguments am I not passing that I am supposed to be?

Comment: It looks like you bootstraped it off a prebuilt pypy for the wrong Python version (since you're getting an error trying to compile code that's valid Python 2 but not valid Python 3). Can you list the exact steps you followed? Especially since (a) there are a lot of options you can choose, and (b) pypy3 is one of those non-default options.

Comment: Also, what version of PyPy did you install for bootstrapping, and what version are you trying to build? I _think_ it may just be as simple as: you need a 2.x `pypy` to bootstrap the translation, even if you're building 3.x, but it may be that, e.g., you can't use PyPy 2.0 to translate PyPy 2.4 whether 2.x or 3.x, or that you can't mix 3.x support and STM support, or… who knows what.

Comment: Using a prebuilt PyPy3 to run the translation. Will install PyPy2 tonight when I get home and try again.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The `bin/rpython` toolchain is written in Python 2.  You need to run it with either CPython 2 or (recommended) PyPy 2.  You can't use CPython 3 or PyPy 3 to run translation.

Comment: I did not know that. Will install PyPy2 tonight and try again.

Comment: That's what I suspected, but I had a hard time finding this documented. That could easily just be me being stupid, or a case of "3.x support just came out, give us a minute to update the build docs", in which case… no problem here. But as written, I think it's not unreasonable for someone to think they not only can but maybe even should use pypy3 to build pypy3, as the asker apparently did.

Comment: You were right. Once I installed pypy2 the translation started working. Thank you both!